# How to select columns based on a list of words in the column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of words, greenwords.

```
print(greenwords)
['eco', 'eco-friendly', 'green', 'organic', 'clean', 'sustainable', 'sustainability', 'carbon', 'emissions']
```

I want a list of columns where the column title contains one of the greenwords.
For example if I wanted a list of all of the columns that contained 'eco' I would do this:

```
eco_columns = [col for col in df.columns if 'eco' in col]
```

Doing this does not work:

```
greenwords_columns = [col for col in df.columns if greenwords in col]
```

Suggestions for capturing all columns with a greenword in the column title?

Comment: please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but you need to check each greenword in each column.  Use sets for faster membership testing.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Organic Icecream', 'Green Energy', 'Taxes'])

# Assumes all `greenwords` are lower case.
greenwords = {'eco', 'eco-friendly', 'green', 'organic', 'clean', 'sustainable', 'sustainability', 'carbon', 'emissions'}
greenwords_columns = [col for col in df 
                      if any(greenword in col.lower() for greenword in greenwords)]

>>> greenwords_columns
['Organic Icecream', 'Green Energy']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list to a string separating each value by `|` with `'|'.join()`. From there you can utilize `str.contains` to return columns that contain any of the `greenwords`:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(greenwords))]
```

You can also pass `case=False` to match case-insensitively:

```
df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('|'.join(greenwords), case=False)]
```